# UK Immigration - is it legal to work remotely from UK as a dependent of a spouse holding a Student Visa

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

My wife and I are US citizens. My wife has been accepted to study abroad as an undergraduate for 1 school year (September'16 - May'17) in London, UK under PBS Tier 4 Student Visa. I intend to travel there with her. I will be her primary means of financial support while there. I'm a software engineer, so my work will be done entirely remotely online for a US based company involving only US bank accounts. As I understand it, I can apply as a dependant to travel to the UK with her. My question is this: will I be allowed to work remotely for a US company receiving payment to US only bank accounts while living in the UK as a dependant of a US exchange student? If not, under what provisions would this be doable?

Comment: You might get a better response at http://expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there a way other than copy/paste to move the question there?

Comment: just reposted on expat. http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8039/uk-immigration-is-it-legal-to-work-remotely-from-uk-as-a-dependent-of-a-spouse

Comment: Question was "self-migrated"